# Capital letters not allowed in android res

Tags: android

Here is a small doubt rather than a question.So a discussion is welcome. I recently was working on an android project and found that if a put a file with a capital letter in its name in the res/drawable then android cribs with a R.stamp error basically a build failure. Say for eg if put a file named picture.png it will build ok but not with say picTure.png . Is it some problem with android or am I missing something?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758228/why-cant-file-names-in-the-drawable-folder-contain-special-characters-or-start-w).You might get your doubt cleared,the reason for that as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file name must contain only [a-z0-9_.]. Observe the console when you build it

Comment: Even though you're right, this doesn't explain anything nor does it answer his question.