# refer to android library project xml resource in application xml resource

Tags: android, xml, resources

I have an Adnroid library project that defines XML resource.

Let's use a selector drawable as an example (but I have problems with strings, styles, etc).

LibProject/res/drawable/button_selector.xml   ... defines a selector

LibProject/res/layout/view.xml .... uses the selector, with no problems

```
 `<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_fly_buttons"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>`
```

Then I want to refer to it in a layout in my App

AppProject/res/layout/view.xml ...

```
`<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sign_up_fly_buttons"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>`
```

But in the App it won't compile or let me reference it. 
I've tried various namespace incantations to try and refer to it with no luck...

Any ideas?

Addition:
I have read that the full-form for such references is:
    @[packagename:]type/id
and if you leave out the package name then the package where this resource file is used.

This an example would be:
    @com.mylibrary:drawable/button_selector

But it doesn't work for me! There must be something wrong with my library setup/import?

My library is in a separate Eclipse Android project, marked as a Library project, and is referenced from my app as a "Dependent Project" and code is built and links in fine.

Comment: how do you include the library ?

Comment: Make sure you follow the file naming convention. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305483/capital-letters-not-allowed-in-android-res

Comment: The library is an eclipse project, marked as a library, and a dependant project in eclipse. All code references work fine, and code and resources are merged into the app - but I can't find how to refer to the resources from xml in my app.

Comment: No files with uppercase letters in the names under /res in either library or app project.

Comment: So, lacking any other solutions - I will have to re-define all these things in my App project....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the problem!

In Eclipse, in my Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Projects" 'tab' I had the library project added.

BUT, I also had to add it to Project Properties -> Android -> Library area as Library Project.

I had done this for others, but had forgotten to do it here.

Thanks to all who tried to figure out my mistake.

Now the resources are merged in correctly and I can refer to them using the "short-form" format without the package name.