# NullPointer while accessing field from fragment in onther fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got a nasty NullPointerException in Fragment while trying to access spinner in another Fragment.
The code, which causes NPE:

```
public class FirstFirst extends Fragment{
    Spinner spinner;
    RadioGroup rg;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_first_fragment, container, false);
        spinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rg=(RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup2);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(arg1==0){
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know, that the Spinner itself is there, I can see it, but if I try to change its visibility with the code above i get the NPE.

@Edit:

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup2" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pow" />
</RadioGroup>
```

@LogCat

```
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841): Process: com.example.kuwa, PID: 12841 
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at com.example.kuwa.FirstFirst$1.onCheckedChanged(FirstFirst.java:26)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:54)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:358)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:130)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-28 13:54:52.681: E/AndroidRuntime(12841):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your `spinnerview` is fine. issue is about your `RadioGroup`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Post your `first_first_fragment.xml` file.

Comment: Please edit your question with the xml code. Try to avoid pasting code in comments.

Comment: @Simple Plan
Are you sure it is that? Because I get the NPE exactly at:
`spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: @user3212350 first remove this  `spinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);`

Comment: @Simple Plan
Ok, I did, still NPE.

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: You can not write IDs with uppercase letters, only [a-z] and _ are allowed

Comment: What is line 26? `rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Comment: It doesn't matter how i wrote ID.
Well it is exactly what it looks like. Adding a on checked change listener to radio group

Comment: @user3212350 I think only [a-z0-9_.] are allowed. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305483/capital-letters-not-allowed-in-android-res

Comment: R.layout.first_first_fragment this layout must contain the spinner in order for u to use it @user3212350

Answer (score 0):

Use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); instead of setVisibility(View.GONE) if you intend to make it visible again later.

Comment: `View.INVISIBLE` does not the same as `View.GONE`. `View.GONE` removes the `View` from the hierarchy and `View.INVISIBLE` it only changes visibility; the `View` is kept on the hierarchy.

Comment: I know the difference, it looks to me like View.INVISIBLE is what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but It doesn't help me with this problem

Comment: Are you still getting the NPE at spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Well then spinner must be null, have you got the correct id name for it? I'm assuming spinner is in the same fragment as the radio group?

Comment: Please post the fragment containing spinner1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rg=(RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup2)
```

instead of this

```
rg=(RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup2)
```

The parameter `view` of [`onViewCreated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is *The View returned by `onCreateView`*

Comment: It didn't change anything, still same exception in same line

Comment: Try changing the ID to lowercase please, just to see if that is the problem

Comment: Why can't I have uppercase letters if IDE makes ID with upperCase letters automatically?

It didn't change anything

Comment: Umm, sorry, I was confused, the restriction is only for drawables. Sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What is name of xml you posted? What is code for first_first_fragment layout. If you don't have spinner with id spinner1 in it, then spinner is null.