# ImageView SetImageResource from string dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview

I would like to set ImageView resource from string dynamically, but I could not do that with following method.

I am using Xamarin/Android to set ImageView resource dynamically as below;

```
ImageView homeItemImage = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.homeItemImage);
int imageId = PlatformProvider.GetImageId(Context, contentTitle.IconImageUrl);
homeItemImage.SetImageResource(imageId);
```

GetImageId function:

```
public static int GetImageId(Context context, string imageName)
{
//   int identifier = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.PackageName);
int identifier = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(context.PackageName + ":drawable/" + imageName, null, context.PackageName);
return identifier;
}
```

I am passing imageName both wasy as "Account.png" or "Account" both returns int as 0.

[image]

[image]

Here is my image folder:

[image: qqq]

And I set them up as AndroidResource (here is shows About.png but Account.png is same way):

[image: qqq]

They show in intellisense:

[image: qqq]

How can I set image source from string?

Comment: See especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35649014/1440565).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that answer is the one I am looking for. This is a weird implementation from xamarin side. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ressources must [not contains special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758228/why-cant-file-names-in-the-drawable-folder-contain-special-characters-or-start) ->

> Each file inside folder is translated into java field name inside
>   R.java class:
>
> drawable\icon.png -> R.drawable.icon Hence the reason for not using
>   special characters inside file names, as they can no be used in Java
>   names.
>
> As for capital letters, I guess that's to avoid one little problem in
>   Windows vs. Linux environment. That's because Linux thinks that
>   Icon.png and icon.png are different files, and Windows thinks that
>   Icon.png and icon.png is the same file. So anyone using Linux can
>   create application that is not compilable on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, this is first option I tried; context.Resources.GetIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.PackageName); and it still returns 0 all the time.

Comment: but why you are doing context.Ressources instead of context.getRessources() ?

Comment: You mean context.PackageName? It is Xamarin implementation over Android and I checked it returns correct package name.

Comment: Yeah you are right, have you try without Capital Letter? It might causes the issue as it's a special character. Related to this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758228/why-cant-file-names-in-the-drawable-folder-contain-special-characters-or-start

Comment: This explains the weirdness more clearly, thanks.